# What CPU did the HP85 have?

Tags: hp

The HP 85, the portable scientific computer from Hewlett Packard in the 1970s, didn't use an off-the-shelf CPU like a Z80 or 8088. Instead, HP designed a custom CPU and used that.

Was this CPU used in any other computer? What was its instruction set and register file like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CPU in the 85 was the [Capricorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capricorn_(microprocessor)), which was used for the [Series 80](http://www.series80.org/) systems. The Wikipedia article linked there gives an overview of the CPU, and the [July 1980](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/1980-07.pdf) and [August 1980](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/1980-08.pdf) issues of HP Journal describe the HP-85 system in detail (including the LSI development process used for the chipset). The Series 80 web site has lots of information on the various systems, including lots of [programming manuals](http://www.series80.org/Manuals/index.html).

The Capricorn has 64 8-bit registers. The first 32 of these are byte- or word-addressable; the second 32 can be addressed as anything from 1- to 8-byte values. The size of each load and store was determined by the instructions used; [this archived Usenet post](https://web.archive.org/web/20091214120841/http://www.vintagecomputers.freeserve.co.uk:80/hp85/processor.htm) has more details.

Answer (score 3):

From a quick Google, looks like it was shared by the HP 83. The instruction set can be found here: http://www.series80.org/PDFs/HP85-Assembler.pdf

Another link I found: http://www.hpmuseum.org/cgi-sys/cgiwrap/hpmuseum/archv013.cgi?read=47629